# How to interact with a MainNet contract from a console?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-invocation, truffle-console

This question may be really dumb, but I fail to understand how to do this.

I have deployed a smart contract to MainNet, and so far I've been interacting with it via Web3JS and Truffle (via the `truffle console`), using promises. For example:

```
ContractOne.deployed().then(function(i) {return i.doSomething({from: "ADDRESS"})})
```

But now, I deployed the contract via Geth/Infura, and truffle console is not working. What is the best way to interact with the deployed contract?

Comment: I reccomend using metamask + remix to interact with the contract, just remember the contract address.

Comment: Thanks! Worked. Write this as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using metamask + remix to interact with the contract, just remember the contract address.